# Gradle Build File org.openapi.generator openApiGenerate Listing Generators openApiGenerators No Output No Error

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the following configuration in my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '4.1.3'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://mavenrepo.schwab.com/nexus/content/groups/public" }
    maven { url "https://mavenrepo.schwab.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "$buildDir/generated/src/main/java"

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/API/POMOrchestrator.v1.json".toString()
    outputDir = "$rootDir/application/".toString()
    apiPackage = "com.schwab.brokerage.party.onborading.api.inbound.rest.controller"
    invokerPackage = "com.schwab.brokerage.party.onborading"
    modelPackage = "com.schwab.brokerage.party.onborading.models.swagger"
    modelNamePrefix = "Party"
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8-localdatetime"
    ]

}

compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate
```

When I execute the following command

```
gradle openApiGenerators --warning-mode all
```

I get the following output with no error (apparent error as I assume it doesn't like my generator name), no outputed classes.

```
> Configure project :
Using method ObjectFactory.property() method to create a property of type Map<K, V> has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0. Please use the Ob
jectFactory.mapProperty() method instead.

> Task :openApiGenerators
The following generators are available:

CLIENT generators:
    - ada
    - android
    - apex
    - bash
    - c
    - clojure
    - cpp-qt5-client
    - cpp-restsdk
    - cpp-tizen
    - csharp
    - csharp-netcore
    - dart
    - dart-jaguar
    - eiffel
    - elixir
    - elm
    - erlang-client
    - erlang-proper
    - flash
    - go
    - go-experimental (experimental)
    - groovy
    - haskell-http-client
    - java
    - javascript
    - javascript-closure-angular
    - javascript-flowtyped
    - jaxrs-cxf-client
    - jmeter
    - kotlin
    - lua
    - nim (beta)
    - objc
    - ocaml
    - perl
    - php
    - powershell
    - python
    - python-experimental (experimental)
    - r
    - ruby
    - rust
    - scala-akka
    - scala-gatling
    - scalaz
    - swift4
    - typescript-angular
    - typescript-angularjs
    - typescript-aurelia
    - typescript-axios
    - typescript-fetch
    - typescript-inversify
    - typescript-jquery
    - typescript-node
    - typescript-rxjs


SERVER generators:
    - ada-server
    - aspnetcore
    - cpp-pistache-server
    - cpp-qt5-qhttpengine-server
    - cpp-restbed-server
    - csharp-nancyfx
    - erlang-server
    - fsharp-functions (beta)
    - fsharp-giraffe-server (beta)
    - go-gin-server
    - go-server
    - graphql-nodejs-express-server
    - haskell
    - java-inflector
    - java-msf4j
    - java-pkmst
    - java-play-framework
    - java-undertow-server
    - java-vertx
    - jaxrs-cxf
    - jaxrs-cxf-cdi
    - jaxrs-cxf-extended
    - jaxrs-jersey
    - jaxrs-resteasy
    - jaxrs-resteasy-eap
    - jaxrs-spec
    - kotlin-server
    - kotlin-spring
    - kotlin-vertx (beta)
    - nodejs-express-server (beta)
    - php-laravel
    - php-lumen
    - php-silex
    - php-slim
    - php-symfony
    - php-ze-ph
    - python-aiohttp
    - python-blueplanet
    - python-flask
    - ruby-on-rails
    - ruby-sinatra
    - rust-server
    - scala-finch
    - scala-lagom-server
    - scala-play-server
    - scalatra
    - spring


DOCUMENTATION generators:
    - asciidoc
    - cwiki
    - dynamic-html
    - html
    - html2
    - openapi
    - openapi-yaml


SCHEMA generators:
    - avro-schema (beta)
    - mysql-schema


CONFIG generators:
    - apache2
    - graphql-schema
    - protobuf-schema (beta)


OTHER generators:





BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

First time trying this and not sure what is wrong.

Ultimately I want to get this working and then specify templates so that I can add lombok annotations (as asked in this question [Gradle Swagger CodeGen DefaultGenerator CodegenConfigurator Add Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628717/gradle-swagger-codegen-defaultgenerator-codegenconfigurator-add-lombok) but not answered yet).  However, I have to get the code gen working first.

Comment: Shouldn't you run the task `openApiGenerate` instead of `openApiGenerators`?

Comment: @philonous from my understanding (which may be flawed) the openApiGenerate is just setting the state variables for the openApiGenerators method in the org.openapi.generator plugin.  Which is why I don't get an error when I do the gradle.  But if that is true it doesn't seem to be picking up my settings.

Comment: @philonous a little more reading on my part and you are correct I am supposed to call the openApiGenerate.  DUH.  The other one is just to list output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the wrong method.  The openApiGenerators just list the generators which is what it was doing.  To generate the output, you have to call the task created above openApiGenerate.  Thanks @philonous for the answer.